# Openlayers 3: interactions on loaded vector features

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

When I use map Interactions as from [this example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.0/examples/draw-and-modify-features.html), creating features collection from scratch everithing goes well:

```
var features = new ol.Collection();
```

but when I try to define map interaction on imported features:

```
var geojsonObject = { ...a well defined (visible) GeoJSON object ...};
var features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(geojsonObject)
```

I get the following exception:

> Error: addEventListener and attachEvent are unavailable. (ol.js:34:302)

when I use features collection in modify interaction definition:

```
modifyInteraction = new ol.interaction.Modify({
                features: features,
                deleteCondition: function(event) {
                    return ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly(event) &&
                    ol.events.condition.singleClick(event);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you attaching the features to a Vector source and to a f.ex ol.layer.Vector?

Comment: Yes it is. The features are correctly attached, and visible, to a  ol.source.Vector in a ol.layer.Vector

Answer (score 0):

this line of code

```
var features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(geojsonObject)
```

returns an array of features and not an `ol.Collection` of features.

On the other hand `ol.interaction.Modify` expects to get `features` parameter as an `ol.Collection` of features. I suspect this is where your error comes from.

Try to chcnge the above line of code to this

```
var features = new ol.Collection(new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(geojsonObject));
```

Note that all the above have impact to the latest version of ol3.